# How to send email from CiviCRM and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, cron-job, php

I am trying to send an email from CiviCRM and Wordpress. The test mailings work, but the scheduled mailings never go beyond being scheduled. I done some research online and I think I have to setup a cron job...I'm not exactly sure.

Can someone please show me how to configure the settings, or direct me to a link that will help me in this matter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the wiki book CiviCRM user and administrator guide for setting up scheduled jobs and cron jobs.

http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/

Comment: I was able to manually execute the scheduled job for the time being. Thank you